# Vim keymapping и кнопка "Context menu"

Tags: vim, клавиатура

Как назначить в Vim действие для кнопки "context menu"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

насколько я понимаю, [пере]определить действия при нажатии на какую-либо кнопку средствами какой-либо программы, в принципе «умеющей» такое делать, возможно лишь в том случае, если событие нажатия поступает программе.

проверьте:

1. запустите `vim`, нажмите <kbd>insert</kbd> или <kbd>i</kbd> для перехода в режим редактирования;
2. нажмите <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> для ввода *escape*-последовательности. «курсор» должен преобразоваться в символ `^` или что-нибудь в этом духе;
3. нажмите клавишу, которая вас интересует. в данном случае — <kbd>menu</kbd>.

если после этого не произошло видимых изменений, значит события нажатия этой кнопки не попадают в программу.

и, соответственно, как-то среагировать на её нажатие программа просто не в состоянии.

а желаемое поведение следует реализовавывать где-то на более «низком» уровне.